# Android get item at specific position in drawer list

Tags: android

I followed [Android training](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to build an activity with a sidebar. Here is my xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My question is : How to get view at specific position in the ListView? I have tried several code but didn't succeed, for example

```
View firstElement = (View) mDrawerList.getAdapter().getItem(5);
```

Or in `ListView.OnItemClickListener` method `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` I have tried :

```
parent.getChildAt(5);
```

Comment: please show your adapter code

Comment: Use recycler view

Answer (score 0):

In itemClick listener you set 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
user param view, this is view returned which was click, instead of using parent.getView(position)